# When to use semicolon and comma in a list of clauses?

Tags: grammar

Case 1

> The probability that event A equals to 1, B equals to 2, and C equals to 3 is X.

and

> The probability that event A equals to 1; B equals to 2, and C equals to 3 is X.

which is correct?

My concern here is according to "https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/commas/how-to-punctuate-between-sentences-using-commas-semicolons-and-colons/", it states that

> "Rule: Use the semicolon if you have two independent clauses connected without a conjunction"

I am not sure if this rule applies to 3 clauses, and if it does apply,

> The probability that event A equals to 1; B equals to 2, and C equals to 3 is X.

looks very weird to me.

Case 2

> The probability that (1) event A equals to 1, (2) B equals to 2, and (3) C equals to 3 is X.

and

> The probability that (1) event A equals to 1; (2) B equals to 2, and (3) C equals to 3 is X.

which is correct?

There is a need to use (1), (2), (3) because my original sentence for "event A equals to 1" is actually quite long. In case2, which way to use "semicolon" is correct?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/84559/2303).

Comment: [Also related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/497024/2303)

Comment: Your use of the semicolon here is incorrect. All the cases you show are lists. The only way I can think of how a semicolon would enter here would be if the list was composed of two parts that were disjoint but thematically connected. Basically, you should be able to replace a semicolon with an m-dash or a period and not change the sentence's underlying meaning, though you would alter its emphasis. In your case, because variable *X* means "A=1 and B=2 and C=3" you can see the problem if you put a period at the end of "A=1".

Answer (score 1):

Among *stops* (I am using the term here to denote a class of punctuation marks, not consonants), the semicolon is intermediate between the comma (“,”) on the one hand, and the period (“.”—*full stop* in British usage) on the other. For usage in separating independent clauses, think of it as a lesser period, giving the reader permission to take a slightly lesser mental/grammatical processing break. For usage in lists, think of it as a greater comma, separating list items that cannot be separated merely by commas because at least one of them *includes* a comma, to separate the main naming of the item from some appositive, non-restrictive relative clause, or other parenthetical addendum. The point I wish to emphasize here is that your confusion is a confusion between these two altogether different usages of the semicolon. [This page from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/a-guide-to-using-semicolons) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons go between two parts of a sentence when each is technically a sentence. "He was victorious in yesterday's mayoral race; work begins now."

Answer (score -1):

Yu-Cheng Chen!

We usually use commas in lists within a sentence:

> I believe that dogs are fun, cats are lazy, and pets are a lot of work.

Semicolons are used between to highly connected thoughts, almost like a conjunction:

> He ran all night and was utterly exhausted by the ordeal; he collapsed.

So, the better formulation given your example is the first:

> The probability that event A equals to 1, B equals to 2, and C equals to 3 is X.

That's because our brains conceptualize this as:

> The probability that event 'A equals to 1', 'B equals to 2', and 'C equals to 3' is X.
>     The probability that event 'A=1', 'B=2', and 'C=3' is X.

As a math guy, I'd probably write:

> The probability that event A=1, B=2, and C=3 is P.

**Note well**, in very sophisticated writing, sometimes semicolons are used, but rarely in common usage.

> Be such that the claims in the book need to be addressed, which is the purpose of this exegesis, then one can conclude certain ideas are tenable such as: the nature of man must be explored soley by philosophers who by their method are more apt to the characteristics of man clearly, no insult meant to other professions; that to explore any collection of human traits is a process which requires time, energy, and a peculiar attention to the psychological is beyond doubt; and it is no small victory for a personality framework to include such a comprehensive and sweeping set of ontological and epistemological features, and thus I give credit where credit is due.